# rctwake : error when using disk option

Tags: debian

When I use the below rctwake command, I get the following error :

```
rtcwake -m disk -s 120
rtcwake: assuming RTC uses UTC ...
rtcwake: wakeup from "disk" using /dev/rtc0 at Tue Oct 10 16:27:29 2017
rtcwake: write error
```

However, when I use the "mem" option, it works fine :

```
rtcwake -m mem -s 120
```

Does this mean that my machine does not support [ACPI state S4 (Suspend-to-disk)](https://linux.die.net/man/8/rtcwake) ?

Here is the result of the command : `dmesg | grep -i acpi`

```
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000cfe90000-0x00000000cfee2fff] ACPI NVS
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000cfee3000-0x00000000cfeeffff] ACPI data
[    0.000000] ACPI: Early table checksum verification disabled
[    0.000000] ACPI: RSDP 0x00000000000F97A0 000024 (v02 DELL  )
[    0.000000] ACPI: XSDT 0x00000000CFEE3080 00005C (v01 DELL   FX09     42302E31 AWRD 00000000)
[    0.000000] ACPI: FACP 0x00000000CFEE7200 0000F4 (v03 DELL   FX09     42302E31 AWRD 00000000)
[    0.000000] ACPI BIOS Warning (bug): 32/64X length mismatch in FADT/Pm1aEventBlock: 32/8 (20160831/tbfadt-603)
[    0.000000] ACPI BIOS Warning (bug): 32/64X length mismatch in FADT/Pm1aControlBlock: 16/8 (20160831/tbfadt-603)
[    0.000000] ACPI BIOS Warning (bug): 32/64X length mismatch in FADT/PmTimerBlock: 32/8 (20160831/tbfadt-603)
[    0.000000] ACPI BIOS Warning (bug): 32/64X length mismatch in FADT/Gpe0Block: 128/8 (20160831/tbfadt-603)
[    0.000000] ACPI BIOS Warning (bug): Invalid length for FADT/Pm1aEventBlock: 8, using default 32 (20160831/tbfadt-708)
[    0.000000] ACPI BIOS Warning (bug): Invalid length for FADT/Pm1aControlBlock: 8, using default 16 (20160831/tbfadt-708)
[    0.000000] ACPI BIOS Warning (bug): Invalid length for FADT/PmTimerBlock: 8, using default 32 (20160831/tbfadt-708)
[    0.000000] ACPI: DSDT 0x00000000CFEE3200 003FFC (v01 DELL   AWRDACPI 00001000 MSFT 03000000)
[    0.000000] ACPI: FACS 0x00000000CFE90000 000040
[    0.000000] ACPI: FACS 0x00000000CFE90000 000040
[    0.000000] ACPI: HPET 0x00000000CFEE73C0 000038 (v01 DELL   FX09     42302E31 AWRD 00000098)
[    0.000000] ACPI: MCFG 0x00000000CFEE7400 00003C (v01 DELL   FX09     42302E31 AWRD 00000000)
[    0.000000] ACPI: SLIC 0x00000000CFEE7440 000176 (v01 DELL   FX09     42302E31 AWRD 00000000)
[    0.000000] ACPI: DMY2 0x00000000CFEE75C0 000080 (v01 DELL   FX09     42302E31 AWRD 00000000)
[    0.000000] ACPI: APIC 0x00000000CFEE7300 000084 (v01 DELL   FX09     42302E31 AWRD 00000000)
[    0.000000] ACPI: SSDT 0x00000000CFEE7CA0 000380 (v01 PmRef  CpuPm    00003000 INTL 20041203)
[    0.000000] ACPI: Local APIC address 0xfee00000
[    0.000000] ACPI: PM-Timer IO Port: 0x408
[    0.000000] ACPI: Local APIC address 0xfee00000
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0x00] high edge lint[0x1])
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0x01] high edge lint[0x1])
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0x02] high edge lint[0x1])
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0x03] high edge lint[0x1])
[    0.000000] ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 0 global_irq 2 dfl dfl)
[    0.000000] ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 9 global_irq 9 high level)
[    0.000000] ACPI: IRQ0 used by override.
[    0.000000] ACPI: IRQ9 used by override.
[    0.000000] Using ACPI (MADT) for SMP configuration information
[    0.000000] ACPI: HPET id: 0x8086a201 base: 0xfed00000
[    0.004038] ACPI: Core revision 20160831
[    0.006974] ACPI: 2 ACPI AML tables successfully acquired and loaded
[    0.089213] PM: Registering ACPI NVS region [mem 0xcfe90000-0xcfee2fff] (339968 bytes)
[    0.116053] ACPI: bus type PCI registered
[    0.116055] acpiphp: ACPI Hot Plug PCI Controller Driver version: 0.5
[    0.132097] ACPI: Added _OSI(Module Device)
[    0.132097] ACPI: Added _OSI(Processor Device)
[    0.132097] ACPI: Added _OSI(3.0 _SCP Extensions)
[    0.132097] ACPI: Added _OSI(Processor Aggregator Device)
[    0.135164] ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:
[    0.135171] ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF9C9C2A6AE400 0002AE (v01 PmRef  Cpu0Ist  00003000 INTL 20041203)
[    0.136186] ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:
[    0.136190] ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF9C9C2A6AC000 000152 (v01 PmRef  Cpu1Ist  00003000 INTL 20041203)
[    0.136496] ACPI: Interpreter enabled
[    0.136513] ACPI: (supports S0 S3 S4 S5)
[    0.136514] ACPI: Using IOAPIC for interrupt routing
[    0.136539] PCI: Using host bridge windows from ACPI; if necessary, use "pci=nocrs" and report a bug
[    0.140809] ACPI: PCI Root Bridge [PCI0] (domain 0000 [bus 00-ff])
[    0.140814] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC: OS supports [ExtendedConfig ASPM ClockPM Segments MSI]
[    0.140819] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC failed (AE_NOT_FOUND); disabling ASPM
[    0.141528] pci 0000:00:19.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[    0.141703] pci 0000:00:1a.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[    0.141877] pci 0000:00:1a.1: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[    0.142050] pci 0000:00:1a.2: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[    0.142241] pci 0000:00:1a.7: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[    0.142435] pci 0000:00:1b.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[    0.142612] pci 0000:00:1d.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[    0.142785] pci 0000:00:1d.1: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[    0.142959] pci 0000:00:1d.2: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[    0.143151] pci 0000:00:1d.7: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[    0.143293] pci 0000:00:1e.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[    0.143420] pci 0000:00:1f.0: quirk: [io  0x0400-0x047f] claimed by ICH6 ACPI/GPIO/TCO
[    0.144962] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKA] (IRQs 3 4 *5 7 9 10 11 12 14 15)
[    0.145026] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKB] (IRQs 3 4 5 7 9 10 11 12 14 15) *0, disabled.
[    0.145090] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKC] (IRQs 3 4 5 7 9 10 *11 12 14 15)
[    0.145153] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKD] (IRQs 3 4 5 7 9 10 *11 12 14 15)
[    0.145216] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKE] (IRQs 3 4 5 7 9 *10 11 12 14 15)
[    0.145279] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKF] (IRQs 3 *4 5 7 9 10 11 12 14 15)
[    0.145342] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNK0] (IRQs *3 4 5 7 9 10 11 12 14 15)
[    0.145404] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNK1] (IRQs 3 4 5 7 *9 10 11 12 14 15)
[    0.145503] ACPI: Enabled 2 GPEs in block 00 to 3F
[    0.145599] PCI: Using ACPI for IRQ routing
[    0.161395] pnp: PnP ACPI init
[    0.161624] system 00:00: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0c02 (active)
[    0.161715] pnp 00:01: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0b00 (active)
[    0.161905] pnp 00:02: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0700 (active)
[    0.162008] system 00:03: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0c02 (active)
[    0.162239] system 00:04: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0c02 (active)
[    0.162378] system 00:05: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0c01 (active)
[    0.162385] pnp: PnP ACPI: found 6 devices
[    0.169255] clocksource: acpi_pm: mask: 0xffffff max_cycles: 0xffffff, max_idle_ns: 2085701024 ns
[    0.698134] ACPI: bus type USB registered
[    0.709147] ACPI: Thermal Zone [THRM] (40 C)
[    8.413994] ACPI: Power Button [PWRB]
[    8.414080] ACPI: Power Button [PWRF]
[    9.929559] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000428-0x000000000000042F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000429-0x0000000000000429 (\PM2S) (20160831/utaddress-247)
[    9.929567] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
[    9.929570] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x00000000000004B0-0x00000000000004BF conflicts with OpRegion 0x00000000000004B8-0x00000000000004BB (\GPO2) (20160831/utaddress-247)
[    9.929573] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
[    9.929574] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000480-0x00000000000004AF conflicts with OpRegion 0x000000000000048C-0x000000000000048F (\GPO) (20160831/utaddress-247)
[    9.929578] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
```

Comment: Run the command under `strace` to find out where that write error comes from.

Comment: Could you paste the output from `dmesg | grep -i acpi`?

Comment: I updated my question with the result of this comment. I hope that helps

Comment: If you scroll down a bit you can see the line `[    0.136513] ACPI: (supports S0 S3 S4 S5)`  This shows your system __should__ support S4.  I'm tracking down a similar issue myself.  I will update if possible

Comment: @tijko Any updates? I'm experiencing the same issue

Comment: @Frederic Were you able to make it work? If you did, can you please post an update.

Comment: @flashburn I suggest posting a question and making a mention to me in the comments.  This is highly dependent on hardware and configuration.

Comment: @tijko I posted it as my own question, [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/730839/rtcwake-error-when-using-disk-mode), but there is no way to use your name in the comments, until you actually post a comment. Would you mind taking a look?