# rtcwake error when using disk mode

Tags: debian

For some reason when I use `rtcwake` with `disk` option I get an error:

```
$ sudo rtcwake -m disk -s 60
[sudo] password for rail:
rtcwake: assuming RTC uses UTC ...
rtcwake: wakeup from "disk" using /dev/rtc0 at Fri Jan  6 22:54:19 2023
rtcwake: write error
```

Everything works fine when I use `mem` option. Has anyone encountered a problem like that? A similar question has already been asked, [rctwake : error when using disk option](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/397266/rctwake-error-when-using-disk-option?noredirect=1#comment1386077_397266). I did ask for an update and was asked to repost as my own question.

Here is the output of my `dmesg | grep -i ACPI`

```
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000c9fa1000-0x00000000ca007fff] ACPI data
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000ca008000-0x00000000cac99fff] ACPI NVS
[    0.000000] reserve setup_data: [mem 0x00000000c9fa1000-0x00000000ca007fff] ACPI data
[    0.000000] reserve setup_data: [mem 0x00000000ca008000-0x00000000cac99fff] ACPI NVS
[    0.000000] efi: ACPI=0xc9fc6000 ACPI 2.0=0xc9fc6000 SMBIOS=0xf0000 TPMFinalLog=0xca995000 MOKvar=0xc61a2000 TPMEventLog=0xc0b87018
[    0.016634] ACPI: Early table checksum verification disabled
[    0.016638] ACPI: RSDP 0x00000000C9FC6000 000024 (v02 DELL  )
[    0.016645] ACPI: XSDT 0x00000000C9FC60A0 0000BC (v01 DELL   CBX3     01072009 AMI  00010013)
[    0.016654] ACPI: FACP 0x00000000C9FF1EB8 00010C (v05 DELL   CBX3     01072009 AMI  00010013)
[    0.016664] ACPI: DSDT 0x00000000C9FC61E8 02BCD0 (v02 DELL   CBX3     01072009 INTL 20091013)
[    0.016670] ACPI: FACS 0x00000000CAC96F80 000040
[    0.016675] ACPI: APIC 0x00000000C9FF1FC8 0000C8 (v03 DELL   CBX3     01072009 AMI  00010013)
[    0.016680] ACPI: FPDT 0x00000000C9FF2090 000044 (v01 DELL   CBX3     01072009 AMI  00010013)
[    0.016685] ACPI: FIDT 0x00000000C9FF20D8 00009C (v01 DELL   CBX3     01072009 AMI  00010013)
[    0.016691] ACPI: MCFG 0x00000000C9FF2178 00003C (v01 DELL   CBX3     01072009 MSFT 00000097)
[    0.016696] ACPI: UEFI 0x00000000C9FF21B8 000042 (v01 INTEL  EDK2     00000002      01000013)
[    0.016702] ACPI: HPET 0x00000000C9FF2200 000038 (v01 DELL   CBX3     00000001 INTL 20091013)
[    0.016707] ACPI: MSCT 0x00000000C9FF2238 000090 (v01 DELL   CBX3     00000001 INTL 20091013)
[    0.016713] ACPI: SLIT 0x00000000C9FF22C8 00002D (v01 DELL   CBX3     00000001 INTL 20091013)
[    0.016718] ACPI: SRAT 0x00000000C9FF22F8 001158 (v03 DELL   CBX3     00000001 INTL 20091013)
[    0.016723] ACPI: SRAT 0x00000000C9FF3450 002358 (v03 DELL   CBX3     00000002 INTL 20091013)
[    0.016729] ACPI: WDDT 0x00000000C9FF57A8 000040 (v01 DELL   CBX3     00000000 INTL 20091013)
[    0.016734] ACPI: SSDT 0x00000000C9FF57E8 0119F4 (v01 DELL   PmMgt    00000001 INTL 20120913)
[    0.016740] ACPI: NITR 0x00000000CA0071E0 000071 (v02 DELL   CBX3     00000001 INTL 20091013)
[    0.016745] ACPI: SLIC 0x00000000CA007258 000176 (v03 DELL   CBX3     01072009 MSFT 00010013)
[    0.016751] ACPI: MSDM 0x00000000CA0073D0 000055 (v03 DELL   CBX3     06222004 AMI  00010013)
[    0.016756] ACPI: BGRT 0x00000000CA007428 000038 (v00                 01072009 AMI  00010013)
[    0.016762] ACPI: TPM2 0x00000000CA007460 000034 (v03        Tpm2Tabl 00000001 AMI  00000000)
[    0.016767] ACPI: ASF! 0x00000000CA007498 0000A0 (v32 INTEL   HCG     00000001 TFSM 000F4240)
[    0.016772] ACPI: Reserving FACP table memory at [mem 0xc9ff1eb8-0xc9ff1fc3]
[    0.016775] ACPI: Reserving DSDT table memory at [mem 0xc9fc61e8-0xc9ff1eb7]
[    0.016777] ACPI: Reserving FACS table memory at [mem 0xcac96f80-0xcac96fbf]
[    0.016778] ACPI: Reserving APIC table memory at [mem 0xc9ff1fc8-0xc9ff208f]
[    0.016780] ACPI: Reserving FPDT table memory at [mem 0xc9ff2090-0xc9ff20d3]
[    0.016782] ACPI: Reserving FIDT table memory at [mem 0xc9ff20d8-0xc9ff2173]
[    0.016783] ACPI: Reserving MCFG table memory at [mem 0xc9ff2178-0xc9ff21b3]
[    0.016785] ACPI: Reserving UEFI table memory at [mem 0xc9ff21b8-0xc9ff21f9]
[    0.016787] ACPI: Reserving HPET table memory at [mem 0xc9ff2200-0xc9ff2237]
[    0.016788] ACPI: Reserving MSCT table memory at [mem 0xc9ff2238-0xc9ff22c7]
[    0.016790] ACPI: Reserving SLIT table memory at [mem 0xc9ff22c8-0xc9ff22f4]
[    0.016792] ACPI: Reserving SRAT table memory at [mem 0xc9ff22f8-0xc9ff344f]
[    0.016793] ACPI: Reserving SRAT table memory at [mem 0xc9ff3450-0xc9ff57a7]
[    0.016795] ACPI: Reserving WDDT table memory at [mem 0xc9ff57a8-0xc9ff57e7]
[    0.016797] ACPI: Reserving SSDT table memory at [mem 0xc9ff57e8-0xca0071db]
[    0.016799] ACPI: Reserving NITR table memory at [mem 0xca0071e0-0xca007250]
[    0.016800] ACPI: Reserving SLIC table memory at [mem 0xca007258-0xca0073cd]
[    0.016802] ACPI: Reserving MSDM table memory at [mem 0xca0073d0-0xca007424]
[    0.016804] ACPI: Reserving BGRT table memory at [mem 0xca007428-0xca00745f]
[    0.016805] ACPI: Reserving TPM2 table memory at [mem 0xca007460-0xca007493]
[    0.016807] ACPI: Reserving ASF! table memory at [mem 0xca007498-0xca007537]
[    0.016900] ACPI: SRAT: Node 0 PXM 0 [mem 0x00000000-0xcfffffff]
[    0.016904] ACPI: SRAT: Node 0 PXM 0 [mem 0x100000000-0x42fffffff]
[    0.074341] ACPI: PM-Timer IO Port: 0x408
[    0.074355] ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0x00] high edge lint[0x1])
[    0.074358] ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0x02] high edge lint[0x1])
[    0.074360] ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0x04] high edge lint[0x1])
[    0.074361] ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0x06] high edge lint[0x1])
[    0.074363] ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0x08] high edge lint[0x1])
[    0.074364] ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0x0a] high edge lint[0x1])
[    0.074365] ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0x0c] high edge lint[0x1])
[    0.074367] ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0x0e] high edge lint[0x1])
[    0.074388] ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 0 global_irq 2 dfl dfl)
[    0.074391] ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 9 global_irq 9 high level)
[    0.074398] ACPI: Using ACPI (MADT) for SMP configuration information
[    0.074400] ACPI: HPET id: 0x8086a701 base: 0xfed00000
[    0.191530] ACPI: Core revision 20210730
[    0.289354] ACPI: PM: Registering ACPI NVS region [mem 0xca008000-0xcac99fff] (13180928 bytes)
[    0.289354] ACPI FADT declares the system doesn't support PCIe ASPM, so disable it
[    0.289354] ACPI: bus type PCI registered
[    0.289354] acpiphp: ACPI Hot Plug PCI Controller Driver version: 0.5
[    0.293954] ACPI: Added _OSI(Module Device)
[    0.293954] ACPI: Added _OSI(Processor Device)
[    0.293954] ACPI: Added _OSI(3.0 _SCP Extensions)
[    0.293954] ACPI: Added _OSI(Processor Aggregator Device)
[    0.293954] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Dell-Video)
[    0.293954] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Lenovo-NV-HDMI-Audio)
[    0.293954] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-HPI-Hybrid-Graphics)
[    0.377170] ACPI: 2 ACPI AML tables successfully acquired and loaded
[    0.383622] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    0.393844] ACPI: Interpreter enabled
[    0.393869] ACPI: PM: (supports S0 S3 S4 S5)
[    0.393870] ACPI: Using IOAPIC for interrupt routing
[    0.393899] PCI: Using host bridge windows from ACPI; if necessary, use "pci=nocrs" and report a bug
[    0.395545] ACPI: Enabled 4 GPEs in block 00 to 3F
[    0.442387] ACPI: PCI Root Bridge [UNC0] (domain 0000 [bus ff])
[    0.442395] acpi PNP0A03:03: _OSC: OS supports [ExtendedConfig ASPM ClockPM Segments MSI EDR HPX-Type3]
[    0.446857] acpi PNP0A03:03: _OSC: platform does not support [SHPCHotplug LTR DPC]
[    0.449314] acpi PNP0A03:03: _OSC: OS now controls [PCIeHotplug PME AER PCIeCapability]
[    0.449316] acpi PNP0A03:03: FADT indicates ASPM is unsupported, using BIOS configuration
[    0.456604] acpi LNXCPU:08: Entry not well-defined, consider updating BIOS
[    0.458371] ACPI: PCI Root Bridge [PCI0] (domain 0000 [bus 00-fe])
[    0.458378] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC: OS supports [ExtendedConfig ASPM ClockPM Segments MSI EDR HPX-Type3]
[    0.458882] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC: platform does not support [PCIeHotplug SHPCHotplug PME AER PCIeCapability LTR DPC]
[    0.458885] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC: not requesting control; platform does not support [PCIeCapability]
[    0.458888] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC: OS requested [PCIeHotplug SHPCHotplug PME AER PCIeCapability LTR DPC]
[    0.458889] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC: platform willing to grant []
[    0.458891] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC: platform retains control of PCIe features (AE_SUPPORT)
[    0.487485] ACPI: PCI: Interrupt link LNKA configured for IRQ 0
[    0.487488] ACPI: PCI: Interrupt link LNKA disabled
[    0.487586] ACPI: PCI: Interrupt link LNKB configured for IRQ 0
[    0.487587] ACPI: PCI: Interrupt link LNKB disabled
[    0.487683] ACPI: PCI: Interrupt link LNKC configured for IRQ 0
[    0.487685] ACPI: PCI: Interrupt link LNKC disabled
[    0.487781] ACPI: PCI: Interrupt link LNKD configured for IRQ 0
[    0.487782] ACPI: PCI: Interrupt link LNKD disabled
[    0.487878] ACPI: PCI: Interrupt link LNKE configured for IRQ 0
[    0.487879] ACPI: PCI: Interrupt link LNKE disabled
[    0.487979] ACPI: PCI: Interrupt link LNKF configured for IRQ 0
[    0.487981] ACPI: PCI: Interrupt link LNKF disabled
[    0.488081] ACPI: PCI: Interrupt link LNKG configured for IRQ 0
[    0.488083] ACPI: PCI: Interrupt link LNKG disabled
[    0.488179] ACPI: PCI: Interrupt link LNKH configured for IRQ 0
[    0.488181] ACPI: PCI: Interrupt link LNKH disabled
[    0.488430] ACPI: bus type USB registered
[    0.488430] PCI: Using ACPI for IRQ routing
[    0.510375] pnp: PnP ACPI init
[    0.512465] pnp: PnP ACPI: found 4 devices
[    0.518591] clocksource: acpi_pm: mask: 0xffffff max_cycles: 0xffffff, max_idle_ns: 2085701024 ns
[    0.594765] ACPI: \_SB_.SCK0.CP00: Found 2 idle states
[    0.595892] ACPI: button: Power Button [PWRB]
[    0.595984] ACPI: button: Power Button [PWRF]
[2946229.409145] ACPI: PM: Preparing to enter system sleep state S4
[2946229.409594] ACPI: PM: Saving platform NVS memory
[2946229.441710] ACPI: PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
[2946229.466737] ACPI: PM: Waking up from system sleep state S4
[2946240.105560] Modules linked in: nf_tables libcrc32c nfnetlink tls cpuid binfmt_misc input_leds intel_rapl_msr nls_iso8859_1 intel_rapl_common sb_edac x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_generic kvm_intel kvm crct10dif_pclmul snd_hda_intel ghash_clmulni_intel snd_intel_dspcfg aesni_intel snd_intel_sdw_acpi dell_wmi crypto_simd snd_hda_codec ledtrig_audio cryptd nouveau snd_hda_core sparse_keymap snd_hwdep dell_smm_hwmon rapl snd_pcm intel_cstate drm_ttm_helper dell_smbios dcdbas ttm wmi_bmof intel_wmi_thunderbolt dell_wmi_descriptor drm_kms_helper snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event hid_generic cec snd_rawmidi rc_core mxm_wmi snd_seq i2c_algo_bit fb_sys_fops snd_seq_device snd_timer syscopyarea sysfillrect mei_me sysimgblt snd video mei soundcore mac_hid sch_fq_codel msr parport_pc ppdev lp parport drm ramoops reed_solomon pstore_blk pstore_zone efi_pstore ip_tables x_tables autofs4 usbhid hid i2c_i801 ahci xhci_pci
[2946283.655245] ACPI: PM: Preparing to enter system sleep state S4
[2946283.655688] ACPI: PM: Saving platform NVS memory
[2946283.686470] ACPI: PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
[2946283.715461] ACPI: PM: Waking up from system sleep state S4
[2946315.042538] ACPI: PM: Preparing to enter system sleep state S4
[2946315.042981] ACPI: PM: Saving platform NVS memory
[2946315.074303] ACPI: PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
[2946315.103200] ACPI: PM: Waking up from system sleep state S4
[2946510.133667] ACPI: PM: Preparing to enter system sleep state S3
[2946510.134022] ACPI: PM: Saving platform NVS memory
[2946510.157235] ACPI: PM: Low-level resume complete
[2946510.157256] ACPI: PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
[2946510.197422] ACPI: PM: Waking up from system sleep state S3
[2950437.125074] ACPI: PM: Preparing to enter system sleep state S4
[2950437.125547] ACPI: PM: Saving platform NVS memory
[2950437.158413] ACPI: PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
[2950437.187914] ACPI: PM: Waking up from system sleep state S4
[2950776.402516] ACPI: PM: Preparing to enter system sleep state S4
[2950776.402859] ACPI: PM: Saving platform NVS memory
[2950776.431397] ACPI: PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
[2950776.459105] ACPI: PM: Waking up from system sleep state S4
[3036991.722263] ACPI: PM: Preparing to enter system sleep state S4
[3036991.722604] ACPI: PM: Saving platform NVS memory
[3036991.752533] ACPI: PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
[3036991.782495] ACPI: PM: Waking up from system sleep state S4
```

My ACPI system does support `S4` mode, `[    0.393869] ACPI: PM: (supports S0 S3 S4 S5)`.

I would appreciate any insights.

**EDIT 2**

Here is output of
`cat /sys/cat /sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id/board_{vendor,name,version}`

```
Dell Inc.
0KJCC5
A00
```

And here is the output of `upower -iupower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT1`

```
  native-path:          (null)
  power supply:         no
  updated:              Wed 31 Dec 1969 04:00:00 PM PST (1673467452 seconds ago)
  has history:          no
  has statistics:       no
  unknown
    warning-level:       unknown
    battery-level:       unknown
    percentage:          0% (should be ignored)
    icon-name:          '(null)'
```

**EDIT**

Here is the output of `uname -a`

```
Linux enterprise 5.15.0-53-generic #59-Ubuntu SMP Mon Oct 17 18:53:30 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

And here is the output of `lscpu`

```
$ lscpu
Architecture:            x86_64
  CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
  Address sizes:         46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
  Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                  8
  On-line CPU(s) list:   0-7
Vendor ID:               GenuineIntel
  Model name:            Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2609 v4 @ 1.70GHz
    CPU family:          6
    Model:               79
    Thread(s) per core:  1
    Core(s) per socket:  8
    Socket(s):           1
    Stepping:            1
    CPU max MHz:         1700.0000
    CPU min MHz:         1200.0000
    BogoMIPS:            3392.08
    Flags:               fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts
                         rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid dca sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_de
                         adline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault epb cat_l3 cdp_l3 invpcid_single pti intel_ppin ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid
                         ept_ad fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rtm cqm rdt_a rdseed adx smap intel_pt xsaveopt cqm_llc cqm_occup_llc cqm_mbm_total cqm_mbm_local dtherm arat pln pts md
                         _clear flush_l1d
Virtualization features:
  Virtualization:        VT-x
Caches (sum of all):
  L1d:                   256 KiB (8 instances)
  L1i:                   256 KiB (8 instances)
  L2:                    2 MiB (8 instances)
  L3:                    20 MiB (1 instance)
NUMA:
  NUMA node(s):          1
  NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-7
Vulnerabilities:
  Itlb multihit:         KVM: Mitigation: VMX disabled
  L1tf:                  Mitigation; PTE Inversion; VMX conditional cache flushes, SMT disabled
  Mds:                   Mitigation; Clear CPU buffers; SMT disabled
  Meltdown:              Mitigation; PTI
  Mmio stale data:       Mitigation; Clear CPU buffers; SMT disabled
  Retbleed:              Not affected
  Spec store bypass:     Mitigation; Speculative Store Bypass disabled via prctl and seccomp
  Spectre v1:            Mitigation; usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user pointer sanitization
  Spectre v2:            Mitigation; Retpolines, IBPB conditional, IBRS_FW, STIBP disabled, RSB filling, PBRSB-eIBRS Not affected
  Srbds:                 Not affected
  Tsx async abort:       Mitigation; Clear CPU buffers; SMT disabled
```

Comment: What does `uname -a` return?  Also could you provide `lscpu`?  These commands will provide some more insight.

Comment: @tijko Done. I added the output for `uname -a` and `lscpu`

Comment: @tijko Any updates?

Comment: @tijko Thank you

Comment: `cat /sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id/board_{vendor,name,version}` can you post these results too?

Comment: `upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT1` and this as well?

Comment: @tijko Done. Added the output for `cat` and `upower`

Comment: I'm going to be looking closer at this today.  Coincidentally the `sysfs` has had changes to the subsystem and my "systems info" program (slstatus) is giving bad data.  If you look the command `upower` is querying DBus for data and I had to do the same but through `d-feet`.

Comment: tbh I didn't even read the updated output from the commands closely until now.  My `upower` command finds my battery and it looks as if yours isn't found at all.

Comment: `echo disk > /sys/power/state` have you set this manually?

Comment: @tijko I did not set it manually. Should I?

Comment: "_Should_" you?  Thats entirely up to you but it is at least worth doing some research on if you are truly wanting to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

There can be a number of things related to hardware that may affect the behavior of the call to `rtcwake`.  As you can already tell by my comments above having diagnostics and data on your operating system and hardware configuration is critical.

That said, I ran a trace on `rtcwake` itself:

```
> sudo strace -Tyfe trace=open,read,write rtcwake -m disk -s 60 2&>~/Output.txt
```

For me this put my machine into "disk" sleep and upon waking and dumping the contents from `Output.txt`:

```
read(3</usr/lib/libc.so.6>, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0P4\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832 <0.000025>
read(3</sys/power/state>, "freeze mem disk\n", 255) = 16 <0.000032>
ssuming RTC uses UTC ."..., 107rtcwake: assuming RTC uses UTC ...
rtcwake: wakeup from "disk" using /dev/rtc0 at Mon Jan 16 03:58:56 2023
) = 107 <0.000028>
write(4</sys/power/state>, "disk\n", 5) = -1 ENODEV (No such device) <2.365407>
```

And its just as I have commented, where `rtcwake` with `"disk"` set as the argument, is writing to `/sys/power/state`.

The equivalent of:

```
> echo disk > /sys/power/state
```

Hope this helps!